# R data frame - fill missing values with condition on another column

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, na, fill

In R, I have a the following data frame:

| Id | Year | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000 | 25 |
| 1 | 2001 | NA |
| 1 | 2002 | NA |
| 2 | 2000 | NA |
| 2 | 2001 | 30 |
| 2 | 2002 | NA |

Each Id has at least one row with age filled.
I would like to fill the missing "Age" values with the correct age for each ID.

Expected result:

| Id | Year | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000 | 25 |
| 1 | 2001 | 25 |
| 1 | 2002 | 25 |
| 2 | 2000 | 30 |
| 2 | 2001 | 30 |
| 2 | 2002 | 30 |

I've tried using 'fill':

```
df %>% fill(age)
```

But not getting the expected results.
Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: try to use `df %>% fill(Age)`

Comment: You need to `group_by(Id) %>% fill(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments were close, you just have to add the `.direction`

```
df %>% group_by(Id) %>% fill(Age, .direction="downup")
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   Id [2]
     Id  Year   Age
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1  2000    25
2     1  2001    25
3     1  2002    25
4     2  2000    30
5     2  2001    30
6     2  2002    30
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your dataframe

`df<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),year=c(2000,2001,2002,2000,2001,2002),age=c(25,NA,NA,NA,30,NA))`

With the `zoo` package, you can try

```
library(zoo)
df<-df[order(df$id,df$age),]
df$age<-na.locf(df$age)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the solution below with the `tidyverse` library.

```
library(tidyverse)    
dt  <- data.frame(Id = rep(1:2, each = 3),
                  Year = rep(2000:2002, each = 2),
                  Age = c(25,NA,NA,30,NA,NA))

dt %>% group_by(Id) %>% arrange(Id,Age) %>% fill(Age)
```

In the code you provided, you didn't use `group_by`. It is also important to `arrange` by Id and Age, because the function `fill` only fills the column down. See for example that data frame, and compare the option with and without `arrange`:

```
dt  <- data.frame(Id = rep(1:2, each = 3),
                  Year = rep(2000:2002, each = 2),
                  Age = c(NA, 25,NA,NA,30,NA))

dt %>% group_by(Id) %>% fill(Age) # only fills partially
dt %>% group_by(Id) %>% arrange(Id,Age) %>% fill(Age) # does the right job
```